# right align item next to semantic-ui's container

Tags: css, flexbox, semantic-ui

my problem is the following:
I want to put an item directly to the right of a semantic-ui container.

```html
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="ui main container">...</div>
    <div class="right-aligned">...</div>
</div>
```

My outer-container is a footer that is sticky to the page.

```css
.outer-container {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 35px;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
}
```

Without having any properties, the `right-aligned` div is pushed to the far right, but I'd like it to be directly next to the container.
I tried using flexbox but I did not succeed, and I suspect this is due to semantic-ui's `container` having the property `margin-right:auto !important`.
I'd be thankful for any pointers.

Comment: As a general point, its best to avoid `!important`. There is almost a way to go without using it, although finding that way can be challenging at times. Margins and flexbox interact in some interesting ways and I don't know if what you want is possible without removing or overriding that margin

Comment: @DJL I agree with you, but the !important property comes from semantic-ui's container. I think I'll have to try by overriding their properties.